# What is the best way to store login credentials on Airflow?

Tags: python, hook, credentials, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I found out there are lot of ways to store it as variables, hooks and other ways using encryption. I would like to know what's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently there 2 ways of storing secrests:

1) **Airflow Variables**: Value of a variable will be hidden if the key contains any words in (‘password’, ‘secret’, ‘passwd’, ‘authorization’, ‘api_key’, ‘apikey’, ‘access_token’) by default, but can be configured to show in clear-text as shown in the image below.

[image]

However, there is a known-bug where anyone with an access to UI can export all the variables which will expose the secrets.

2) **Airflow Connections**:

You can use the **Passwords** field in Airflow connections which will encrypt that field if you had installed the `crypto` package (`pip install apache-airflow[crypto]`). The password field would just appear as blank in the UI as shown in the screenshot.

More on Securing connections: https://airflow.apache.org/howto/secure-connections.html

[image]

I recommend the 2nd approach as even if someone gets access to the UI, he/she won't be able to get your secrets. Keep in mind though that you need to install the `crypto` package for this.

You can then access the secrets as below:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

connection = BaseHook.get_connection(CONN_ID)
slack_token = connection.password
```

You can set the `CONN_ID` as the name of your connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to save and import multiple username and password for server, database and API. May I know the 2nd approach works? Could you please gimme a short example code of saving and importing it in the python code?

Comment: Can you link to the known security bug? I tried finding it and couldn't.

Comment: @kaxil thanks! I see you're the one with intimate knowledge of this bug :)

Comment: does anyone know if the security bug, where the passwords could be exported as variable is still a thing? We tried it out but the exported variables are encrypted 
({
    "password": "********"
}). Could someone provide the link to the bug?

Comment: `airflow.hooks.base_hook.BaseHook` is deprecated in airflow>=2.5.3. use `from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook`